# Can you selectively sync only some instance of a setting (if that setting is an array)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

### Question

I'm using GitLens, which has fantastic remote integration. However, I'm not sure if I should have certain remotes sync between machines. For instance:

```
"gitlens.remotes" : [
    {
       "domain": "bitbucket.corporate-domain.com",
       "name": "Corporate BitBucket",
       "type": "Bitbucket Server",
    },
    {
       "domain": "github.com/personal",
       "name": "Personal GitHub",
       "type": "GitHub",
    }
]
```

Now, I know that one can put `"gitlens.remotes"` into `"settingsSync.ignoredSettings"` and that will keep it from syncing. Fair enough. *But*, what if I don't mind the second remote syncing between machines, and I *only* want to prevent the first remote from syncing? Can't put `"gitlens.remotes[0]"` into `"settingsSync.ignoredSettings"`, that doesn't work.

### Alternatives

#### Workspace Settings

I'm not sure this is what I want because I have multiple projects on both machines, and I'd like to have the settings sync between those projects. Having to put the same remotes settings into each workspace seems like overkill to me. I have thought about creating a `settings.local.json` file and saving it on my work machine, though, and from whence I could copy the settings. (I know VSCode *used to* support a file, but no longer does.)

#### Profile Switcher

I have this extension and have been tinkering with it, but I don't see how it would work here as it would still sync the setting between machines, it would just have it in another JSON object.

---

Note that it isn't a huge deal or urgent problem, I'm just curious if this functionality exists. And if it doesn't, and there are other ways to do this, I am all ears.